# Why Cronin Effect Happens?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering, quantum-chromodynamics

I'm looking for explanation on [Cronin effect](http://www.google.com/search?q=Cronin+effect) but unfortunately there's no Wikipedia entry or self-contained paper to start from. The statement of this effect is that:

> *"At leading order, multiple scattering only affect the momentum
>   distribution of the final particles, but not their total number. The
>   suppression at small p is compensated by an increase at larger p."*

Can someone please explain why? I'm looking for a calculation based answer and not just qualitative discussion.

Comment: I would love to see an answer before the bounty will expire.

Comment: where did you get this quote from?

Comment: would you be interested in explanation in terms of hadrons and partons?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the following article is relevant: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0402256 (published in Nucl. Phys. A). (The phrase you quote is probably from lectures http://www.physik.uni-bielefeld.de/~borghini/Teaching/HIC-Seminar/SoSe2013/Francois_SPhT2006-1.pdf by one of the authors of the article):

> "The Cronin effect was discovered in proton-nucleus collisions in the
>   late 70's[62-64]. The effect observed was a hardening of the
>   transverse momentum spectrum in proton-nucleus collisions, relative to
>   proton-proton collisions, that sets in at transverse momenta of order
>   $k_\perp \sim 1-2$~GeV, and disappears at much larger $k_\perp$'s. A
>   corresponding depletion was seen at low transverse momenta,
>   accompanied by a softening of the spectrum. At that time, and indeed
>   subsequently, the effect was interpreted as arising from the multiple
>   scatterings of partons from the proton off partons from the nucleus
>   [65]. As a result of such scatterings, the partons acquire a
>   transverse momentum kick, shifting their momenta from lower to higher
>   values, hereby causing the observed respective depletion and
>   enhancement. At high $k_\perp$, the higher twist effects, which, in
>   the language of perturbative QCD, are responsible for multiple
>   scattering[66,67] are suppressed by powers of $k_\perp$.  The relative
>   enhancement of the cross-sections at moderate $k_\perp$'s should thus
>   die away -- and indeed, the data seemed to suggest as much.  Though a
>   qualitative understanding of the previously observed Cronin effect was
>   suggested by perturbative QCD, a quantitative agreement for all its
>   features (such as, for instance, the flavor dependence) is still
>   lacking."

The words "At leading order" in the phrase you quote suggests that this is a result of calculations. It looks like the following article is relevant: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0201311v1.pdf :"the leading twist contribution always consists of one hard scattering on the parton level". This is almost exactly what is said in the phrase you quote. So maybe you should find out more about this "twist expansion". Probably, the phrase is about the leading order of this expansion.

Comment: I already came across the relevant papers you attach but I'm looking for calculations and less for a qualitative approach.

Comment: @Yair: That was not clear from your question:-)

Comment: @Yair you should extend your question and specify that you want mathematical explanation of effect. Also, I think it's more related to Nuclear Physics and QCD, consider to change some tags.

Comment: As mentioned, the leading twist term is a single partonic scatter, which will be of form 2 partons -> 2 partons. So that's why there is the comment about leading order preserving multiplicity: you need to go to higher orders to get a real parton emission which would increase the multiplicity. But the LO diagrams can still change kinematics. It's remarkably hard to find an introductory paper on higher-twist corrections in pQCD (in the OPE formalism), but this (e-)book gives some introduction that's easier than the state of the art papers: http://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~yuri/BPQCD/BPQCD.pdf

Comment: If you'll write a full answer I'll credit you with the bounty. However, there's less than 24h to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Usually, Cronin effect is given in terms of the central-to-peripheral
>   nuclear modification factor for $dAu$ collisions at [midrapidity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/midrapidity)
>
> $$   R^h_{CP}(p_t)=
> > \frac{(1/N^C_{coll})dN^h/p_tdp_t(C)}{(1/N^P_{coll})dN^h/p_tdp_t(P)} $$
>
> where $C$ central, $P$ reipheral, $N_{coll}$ the average number of
>   inelastic $NN$ collisions.If hadronization is by fragmentation, which
>   is a factorizable subprocess, the FFs for any given $h$ should cancel
>   in the ratio of desribed equation, so $R^h_{CP}$ should be independent of
>   h.
>
> However, the data show that $R^p_{CP}(p_T)>R^{\pi}_{cp}(p_T)$ for all
>   $p_T$ > 1 GeV/c, when C = 0–20% and P = 60–90% [centralities](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0205072).
>
> Clearly, initial-state interaction  is not able to explain this phenomenon, 
>   which strongly suggests the medium-dependence of hadronization. The data further
>   indicate that the $p_T$ dependence of $R^h_{CP}(p_T)$ peaks at $p_T$ ∼
>   3 GeV/c for both $p$ and $\pi$, reminiscent of the $p/\pi$ ratio at
>   fixed centrality in $A_uA_u$ collisions although the $C/P$ ratio for
>   $dAu$ collisions is distinctly different.

["Quark-gluon Plasma 4" by Rudolph C. Hwa](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814293288) , 2010, p. 279

FF - [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_%28particle_physics%29#Jet_fragmentation) function - generally, FF is treated as a black box with a
parton going in and a hadron going out, whereas in the [recombination model](http://www.kfki.hu/~gribov75/PROC/pisut_gb75.pdf)(RM) we open up the black box and treat the outgoing hadron as the product of recombination of shower partons, whose distributions are to be determined from the FFs.