# What is Cronin effect?

Tags: particle-physics

I am doing a Master in Physics. My area of research is experimental particle physics. During the literature review, I have read this statement many times, this happens because of the Cronin effect, then I started to understand what is Cronin effect, but unfortunately did not found any source. Please explain clearly and in easy wording about the [Cronin effect](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=cronin+effect).

Comment: "I have read this statement many times": where? Links or citations would help us to help you better.

Comment: Perhaps start somewhere like https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.232303

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88496/) has quite a few references...